# stanford core NLP RNNCoreAnnotations node vector

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

What does the:

```
public static SimpleMatrix getNodeVector(Tree tree)
```

of the RNNCoreAnnotations class return exactly?
It is a vector of 25 decimal values, but what do they represent?

Comment: It's clear that returned value is of type `SimpleMatrix`. Refer to your library OR code as to what is the behaviour of SimpleMatrix class!!!

Comment: Thank you, but I was interested in what these values represent.It seems my question was ambiguous, sorry about that! Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns the distributed representation of the node, which is a vector. This corresponds to the vectors *a*, *b*, *c*, *p<sub>1</sub>*, and *p<sub>2</sub>* in Section 4 of the paper about the work: http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/SocherEtAl_EMNLP2013.pdf . It is not easily human interpretable, but a function of it predicts the node's sentiment, as explained in the paper.